# Liferay: Migrating CronTrigger from 6.2 to 7.1

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7, crontrigger

I want to migrate a class from **6.2 CE** **to 7.1 DXP**.
In the 6.2 version of the functionality i want to migrate uses **CronTrigger** of the package **com.liferay.portal.kernel.scheduler**.

I cannot find a substitution for that in 7.1, could it be that this functionality was removed from liferay alltogether? In that case i would use CronTrigger functionality from quartz and try to make a workaround.

Or is there a smarter, maybe liferay supported, way for this?

Comment: See https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-7-ce-liferay-dxp-scheduled-tasks